# Jena: How to obtain the values of a multiple-valued property?

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I define a multiple-valued object property `hasAuthor` in my ontology `literature`. There is an individual `book-1` whose `hasAuthor`'s are `writer-1` and `writer-2`. If I want to obtain the authors of `book-1`, I can write something like

```
Resource r;  // r represents the individual book-1
r.getRequiredProperty(literature.hasAuthor).getObject().toString();
```

or

```
r.getPropertyResourceValue(literature.hasAuthor).toString();
```

But both of them only return the first value `writer-1`, and `writer-2` is ignored.

How should I modify my code to obtain all the authors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the get* operations get single items and list* return iterators over multiple things.

Use .listProperties(property) -> StmtIterator.

Answer (score 2):

A Jena `Resource` has a method [`listProperties`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#listProperties%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property%29) that you can use to iterate over the statements having the resource as subject and with the given property.  Here's an example that describes the [RDF Primer](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/) and its two editors (called authors in this example, for the sake of aligning with your example).

```java
public class MultipleProperties {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ns = "http://www.example.com/";
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.setNsPrefix( "", ns );
    Property hasAuthor = model.createProperty( ns + "hasAuthor" );

    Resource rdfPrimer = model.createResource( "http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/" );
    Resource fm = model.createResource( ns + "FrankManola" );
    Resource em = model.createResource( ns + "EricMiller" );

    rdfPrimer.addProperty( hasAuthor, fm );
    rdfPrimer.addProperty( hasAuthor, em );

    System.out.println( "== The Model ==" );
    model.write( System.out, "N3" );

    System.out.println( "\n== The Properties ==" );
    StmtIterator it = rdfPrimer.listProperties( hasAuthor );
    while( it.hasNext() ) {
      Statement stmt = it.nextStatement();
      System.out.println( " * "+stmt.getObject() );
      System.out.println( "   * "+stmt );
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
== The Model ==
@prefix :        <http://www.example.com/> .

<http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/>
      :hasAuthor :EricMiller , :FrankManola .

== The Properties ==
 * http://www.example.com/EricMiller
   * [http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/, http://www.example.com/hasAuthor, http://www.example.com/EricMiller]
 * http://www.example.com/FrankManola
   * [http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-primer/, http://www.example.com/hasAuthor, http://www.example.com/FrankManola]
```